# Where are the install logs for macOS bootable external installer

Tags: macos, install

With the more recent macOS installers, using `createinstallmedia` to make bootable installers is widespread practice now.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372

When we take that drive to a Mac to erase it and install a clean OS - do the installer logs with any errors get saved to the external or internal disk or do we need to inspect/ save / send them to Apple before we quit the installer?

Answer (score 5):

The macOS install log is always on the target drive in `/var/log/install.log`.